# How to retrieve all rows of ParseObject in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

On googlemap if my app user creates any maker I am storing that marker location details as a parse object,
[image: here it is]
now I want to retrieve all location details of all markers, how to do it. I already gone through parse.com tutorial links.

Comment: What have you tried, what issues are you facing? You say that you've gone through all the tutorials on Parse.com, yet there are plenty on how to query for a list of objects, so what makes those solutions not work for you?

Answer (score 16):

Try something like....

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("GreenMarkers");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> markers, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // your logic here
        } else {
            // handle Parse Exception here
        }
    }
});
```

This should get all items from the "GreenMarkers" table.

Comment: That will get at most 100 rows, or if you change the limit it will get up to 1000 rows. If you need more than that you'll need to page through the results, or rethink why the code needs so much raw data.